# ALSA - using pause, resume, stop <-> blocking mode

Tags: alsa

Only a basic question: Must I use nonblocking-mode to pause, resume and stop the stream? Or is there a way to use blocking mode and pause ...?

Comment: What do you think prevents you from pausing a device in blocking mode?

Comment: I am starting with this API. I recognized, that I didn't find a way to pause in blocking mode with snd_pcm_pause. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Just call `snd_pcm_pause()`.

Comment: If I put snd_pcm_pause after snd_pcm_writei it waits until snd_pcm_writei has finished in blocked mode.

Comment: The whole point of blocking mode is that your program is suspended until the data has been written. If you don't want to block, don't use blocking mode. (There's nothing special about pausing; this applies to *anything* else your code could do.)

Comment: That was my question. If there is no way to pause while the stream is playing, it doesn't make sense to pause after the end of the stream.

Comment: snd_pcm_writei() returns when it has written the data to the buffer, which is before that data is played.